# How to get the number of hours since, from a UTC timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, utc, python-datetime

I have a UTC timestamp and I'd like to calculate the number of hours from then to now in Python. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: The `datetime` module should be useful here. `datetime.datetime.now()` will give you the current time, and `datetime.fromutctimestamp()` should help you converting an existing UTC timestamp.

Comment: [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime` is the module to use here (due to UTC requirement):

```
def hours_since(timestamp):
    import datetime
    return (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)).total_seconds() / 3600.
```

Example:

```
hours_since(1385715744.206451)
0.18432851777777778
```

Comment: -1: it should be `utcfromtimestamp()` (returns time in UTC), not `fromtimestamp()` (returns local time). Seconds since the epoch (the timestamp) are not in UTC nor any other timezone. Though it is easy to convert the timestamp into UTC time if we ignore leaps seconds.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Change made. I didn't notice the inconsistency because my test computer was set to UTC time.

Comment: +2 Though, the phrase *"timestamp must be a UTC time stamp"* still doesn't make sense (it is a common error but it doesn't make it true through repetition though it would make it true in ordinary speech :) Python works with seconds since the Epoch (and stdlib would probably break if it is not POSIX timestamp).